# Redactor won't allow simple styling in heading tags

Tags: redactor

On a fairly fresh site (and also on some more built up sites) I noticed that Redactor is preventing you from doing the following:

1. Create a heading such as an H1 or H2 with two or more words
2. Select only one of the words in the heading
3. Attempt to apply styling, such as bold or italic to that word

This should result in some simple markup such as:

```
<h1>My list of <strong>words</strong></h1>
```

But it does not apply this styling.

Is this a bug with redactor? Intended behavior? Do you know a clever work around that would utilize Redactor's native buttons?

Edit:

- The `Clean Up HTML?` field is unchecked on this redactor settings type.
- This bug seems to be a redactor bug, it exists on http://imperavi.com/redactor/

Comment: Looks like a Redactor bug to me, too. I've send them an email about it.  Going to vote to close this question as it's a bug.

Comment: Did they respond back on that bug report, Brad? This issue is not a minor one (you can't string / em in headings!), but still exists on 10.1.1, which you can test on http://imperavi.com/redactor/.

Comment: @BradBell forgot the at-mention with the previous comment. So now again, did they respond? I just checked and they released 10.1.2 in the meantime, but the bug's still not fixed. :(

Comment: @carlcs - Oops. Forgot to update with their response, which I don't really agree with. `"For code streamlining purposes and to implement more of best practices and to improve compatibility, Redactor doesn't allow inline styling of headings (starting with version 10); please, advise your client to use CSS instead, whenever possible."`

Comment: @carlcs So essentially "Bug Status: Closed Won't Fix".

Comment: @BradBell WHAT?? This isn't true.

Comment: Do they mention any references for their "best practices"?

Comment: @carlcs Nope... makes no sense to me, either.

Comment: @BradBell Not to belabor the issue, but how is a client end-user supposed to achieve the desired result "use[ing] CSS instead"? My question is how can a portion of a heading be emphasized or bolded? The only way to target words within a tag is by placing another tag inside said heading, which is what they won't support.

Comment: I had to edit redactor.js to get this to work, what a joke. Line 4165 comment out: if (this.utils.isCurrentOrParent('PRE') || this.utils.isCurrentOrParentHeader()) return;

Comment: I received a similar response from Imperavi. It seems like our options are either to toggle code view and add tags manually or to build a custom redactor plugin to handle the desired heading functionality.

Comment: I'm just starting to get into Craft, and am evaluating its suitability for a site with significant text formatting. From what I've seen, Redactor seems like more of a liability than anything else... it doesn't even have a "Remove Styles" button, FFS. So if you accidentally bold something, good luck unbolding it without diving into the source! What are the chances of Craft switching over to a different, more mature WYSIWYG editor, such as CK Editor?

Comment: Imperavi released Redactor II 1.0.2 today and *finally* added inline formatting in headings and tables. Please re-open so I can add an answer, thanks! @Simon

Comment: @BradBell you did not yet abandon Redactor for future Craft releases (2.5, 3.0), did you?

Comment: @carlcs Nope. Redactor II will be in 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

Rich Text fields in Craft have several options to them that can affect code output. In your field settings, make sure you don't have `Clean up HTML?` ticked. As the description reads, this option:

> Removes spans, empty tags, and most style attributes on save.

Without seeing your field, this is a wild guess at what could be the problem.

Comment: Thanks Jamie, I forgot to mention that the `Clean up HTML?` field is unchecked. I'll add that to my question for clarity.

Comment: @MichaelThomas Ah, in that case ignore me! :)

Comment: If you want to get your hack on change line 4295 to if (this.utils.isCurrentOrParent('PRE')) return;